# Sort by X but print Y

Tags: java, sorting, max

In my java program, there are objects of a class called `salesperson`.

These objects have an attribute called `sales` and an attribute called `name`.

I want to compare the **sales values** to **find the largest value** and then **print out the name** of the object that has the highest sale value.

How I did it was

```
double highSales;
String highSalesString;
highSales=first.getJanSales();
        highSalesString=first.getSName() +" "+ first.getTitle();
        if (second.getJanSales()>highSales)
        {
            highSales=second.getJanSales();
            highSalesString=second.getSName() +" "+ second.getTitle();
        }
        if (third.getJanSales()>highSales)
        {
            highSales=third.getJanSales();
            highSalesString=third.getSName() +" "+ third.getTitle();
        }
```

I feel like there's a much simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

### `Comparator`

You just got to use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) or implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) accordingly.

For example

```java
List<SalesPerson> persons = ...

persons.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(SalesPerson::getSales).reverseOrder());

SalesPerson personWithMostSales = persons.get(0);
System.out.println(personWithMostSales.getName());
```

If all you want is just this one entry, you do not have to sort the whole list:

```java
SalesPerson personWithMostSales = persons.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(SalesPerson::getSales).reverseOrder())
    .orElseThrow();
System.out.println(personWithMostSales.getName());
```

There is also [`Collections.max(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,java.util.Comparator)) which you can use instead of the stream.

---

### `Comparable`

If you think that sorting `SalesPerson` by their `sales` is a reasonable thing to do by default (a so called **natural order**), you can also let them implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) accordingly:

```java
public class SalesPerson implements Comparable<? super SalesPerson> {
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SalesPerson other) {
        return -1 * Integer.compare(sales, other.sales);
    }
}
```

and then you could put them into a sorted collection such as `TreeSet` and it would keep them sorted for you already. Note however that such collections usually do not allow that you modify `sales` while the persons have already been added to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to compare the sales values to find the largest value and then print out the name of the object that has the highest sale value.

I would skip the sorting since all you want seems to be the name of the person that had maximum sales.  Assuming your sales people are in a List you can do it as follows:

The record for demo purposes (behaves like a class).

```
record SalesPerson(String getName, double getSales) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + getName + ", " + "Sales: $" + getSales;
    }
}
```

Create some data

```
List<SalesPerson> sales = List.of(new SalesPerson("John", 492.44 ),
        new SalesPerson("Mary", 688.68), new SalesPerson("Bob", 533.22));
```

- this streams the SalesPerson instances
- then using a comparator, finds the maximum based on the sales value.
  `max` returns an `Optional<SalesPerson>`.

```
Optional<SalesPerson> bestSalesPerson = sales.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(SalesPerson::getSales));

if (bestSalesPerson.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(bestSalesPerson.get());
}
```

Prints

```
Name: Mary, Sales: $688.68
```

If you don't wish to use a stream you can do it with a loop.

- if the list is not empty assign the first person to `best`
- then iterate over the list, comparing each candidate's record to the current best and adjust as required.  Extra checks are added in case the list is empty. These can be eliminated if not necessary.

```
SalesPerson best = null;
if (!sales.isEmpty()) {
    best = sales.get(0);
}
for (int i = 1; i < sales.size(); i++) {
    SalesPerson candidate = sales.get(i);
    if (candidate.getSales > best.getSales) {
        best = candidate;
    }
}

if (best != null) {
    System.out.println(best);
}
```